# Python file transfer

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, synchronization, dropbox

I wrote a python app which transfers files via sockets to a server. It always works, but my question is: is that a good way to transfer files from desktop client to server via sockets? How, for example, do Google Drive or Dropbox desktop clients syncronize files (as I know for already existent files GD client sends only changes, like rsync), but what about new files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clients usually upload files via HTTP-POST. This even applies to when the client sends only the changes. [Here's](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/) an example on how to POST a file with Python.

The only benefit of using a socket is for the server to asynchronously contact the client, for example so that it can inform the client of a file it should download, as DropBox etc. do.

Comment: Thank you, for your response, but can I resume or pause uploads using POST?

Comment: Good question, all the Python libraries I'm familiar with are designed to make uploads simple, and don't provide pause/resume functionality. So you'd have to implement the POST yourself, by adding pause/resume to your favorite library's source code.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider packaging the file into a torrent, and transferring it that way. Torrents have LOTS of error recovery. Many large companies, for example, Blizzard, use torrents to deliver content to their users.

You'll still need a way to transfer the torrent info of course

See python package `libtorrent` and the server software called `opentracker`

I've also done file transfer with sockets, which is fine if the internet connection is uninterrupted, and you don't want to parallel stream.